# How to compare numpy arrays in terms of similarity

Tags: python, numpy

I am given two numpy-arrays: One of dimensions `i x m`and the other of dimensions `j x m`. What I want to do is, loop through the FirstArray and compare each of its elements with each of the elements of the SecondArray. When I say 'compare', I mean: I want to compute the Euclidean distance between the elements of FirstArray and SecondArray. Then, I want to store the index of the element of SecondArray that is closest to the corresponding element of FirstArray, and I also want to store the index of the element of SecondArray that is second closest to the element of the FirstArray.

In code this would look somewhat similar to this:

```
        smallest = None
        idx = 0
        for i in range(0, FirstArrayRows):
            for j in range(0, SecondArrayRows): 
                EuclideanDistance = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(FirstArray[i,:] - SecondArray[j,:]))) 
                if smallest is None or EuclideanDistance < smallest:
                    smallest = EuclideanDistance
                    idx_second = idx
                    idx = j
           Closest[i] = idx 
           SecondClosest[i] = idx_second
```

And I think this works. However, there are two cases when this code fails to give the correct index for the second closest element of SecondArray:

1. when the element of SecondArray that is closest to the element of FirstArray is at j = 0.
2. when the element of SecondArray that is closest to the element of FirstArray is at j = 1.

So I wonder: Is there a better way of implementing this? 
I know there is. Maybe someone can help me see it?

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use numpy's broadcasting to your advantage. Compute the Euclidean distance with all elements of the second array in a single operation. Then, you can find the two smallest distances using argpartition.

```
import numpy as np

i, j, m = 3, 4, 5
a = np.random.choice(10,(i,m))
b = np.random.choice(10,(j,m))
print('First array:\n',a)
print('Second array:\n',b)

closest, second_closest = np.zeros(i), np.zeros(i)
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    dist = np.sqrt(((a[i,:] - b)**2).sum(axis=1))
    closest[i], second_closest[i] = np.argpartition(dist, 2)[:2]

print('Closest:', closest)
print('Second Closest:', second_closest)
```

Output:

```
First array:
 [[3 9 0 2 2]
 [1 2 9 9 7]
 [4 0 6 6 4]]
Second array:
 [[9 9 2 2 3]
 [9 9 0 2 3]
 [1 1 6 7 7]
 [5 7 0 4 4]]
Closest: [3. 2. 2.]
Second Closest: [1. 3. 3.]
```

Comment: Does this solution ensure that `closest` actually contains the most similar vector? It could contain the second closest vector, couldn't it? `np.argpartition` does only guarantee that entries before the given idx are smaller, but not sorted.

Comment: My solution is a bit of a hack. Argpartition does in theory only guarantee that the elements before idx are smaller, ie, the element at idx is in its correct sorted position. But because of how the partitioning is implemented, np.argpartition(array, k) for k<=2 always guarantees that items before k are in sorted order. In this case, thus, item 0 and 1 are sorted. You can try running arpartition for different values of idx to verify this if you want. This solution wouldn't work if there was something like 'third closest' or '4th closest' and on - then you'd be better off sorting the array : )